# Проблема при создании SSH подключения

Tags: сеть, ssh

Делаю SSH подключение на микроконтроллере (МК). Подключаюсь к устройству через PuTTY и проверяю каждый этап через wireshark.Первый этап Protocol проходит успешно, после чего мне присылают 2е сообщение Server: "Key exchange init" и PuTTu выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для формирования сообщения от МК брал пакеты между проверенным устройством и PuTTY:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, есть ли расписанное подключение SSH, по этапам, побайтно (как header)?
Или в чем ошибка при формировании пакета?

*использовать готовые библиотеки нет возможности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поменял порт с назначенного на 22 -й и wireshark стал определять мои сообщения как ssh.

Это позволило найти ошибку. Она была связанна с предыдущим сообщением (обмен протоколами), а конкретно с неверно указанной длиной сообщения для TCP.